# Configure Multiple OS on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion, boot-camp, multi-boot

I just had a iMac delivered today. I want to configure it in following way for testing on various versions.

I need to set up 10.7 Server, 10.6 Server and Windows 2008 server and possibly one more windows OS.

How do I do it?

I just know that, with one of the OS X version say(10.7), I can have can have a boot camp working for with window server 2008, Can I have more than one windows OS in boot camp?

Comment: Just use virtual machines? Both 10.7 and 10.6 Server can be virtualized legally. You save yourself quite a bit of hassle with setting up multiple partitions and a custom boot loader.

Comment: I know but its for testing on physical machine.

Comment: Hey Common!! Put a reason before downvoting!

Comment: Might want to look at: http://refit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple physical OSes, an iMac is the wrong way to go about it. You're better off with a PC where you can manage the boot records a little better.

That said, you might be able to get away with one Windows boot camp partition, which you can then modify using the boot config tool to allow booting off separate VHDs for your other OSes. Your performance hit is negligible because the VHDs are the only bottleneck - everything else is native.

This is a theory. I've never tried it, and I don't know if it will even work.

Disclosure: I own an iMac.